# Plain es6 promise; how to do n arbitrary operations?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

I have two simple methods

```
// send a single command
sendCommand(command) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this._commands.write(command, (response) => {
      response === '?' : reject(command) : resolve(command);
    });
  });
}

// has to send multiple commands and wait for the result
sendArray(name, array) {
  let bits = _.chunk(array, 4);
  _.each(bits, (bit, index) => {
    this.sendCommand(`QD ${name}[]${bits.join('\r')}\\`);
  });
}
```

However, is there any way for this array be sent through the promises iteratively with *plain es6 promises*? Eg:

```
// for every bit in bits
this.sendCommand(bit1)
  .then(() => { this.sendCommand(bit2) })
  // ...
  .then(() => { this.sendCommand(bitN) })
  .catch(console.log);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
let allBitsPromise = _.chunk(array, 4).reduce(function (p, bit) {
    return p.then(() => sendCommand(bit));
}, Promise.resolve());
```

would work.

The least obvious part of this (to me, anyway) is that if the callback passed to `then` returns a promise `p` then the original promise is resolved when `p` is. So a promise like

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
});
```

Is only resolved when the promise returned by the callback is resolved by `setTimeout`.

Comment: Nice application of reduce!

Answer (score 2):

Keep a reference to the promise returned by the function and chain the `.then` call on it:

```
let promise = Promise.resolve();
_.each(bits, (bit, index) => {
  promise = promise.then(() => this.sendCommand(`QD ${name}[]${bits.join('\r')}\\`));
});
promise.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Note that this will send the data *sequentially*, which I assume is what you want.